# System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri

Tags: android, image, sqlite, android-studio, android-bitmap

I have an SQLite database and image URI stored there. I want to show the image using the URI. If I hardcode the URI it works `mImageView.setImageURI("content://media/external/images/media/47");` but if I retrieve it from the database it does not

> Database get method

```
public Cursor getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }
```

> Utility method

```
public String monitorData() {
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
    while(data.moveToNext()){
        listData.add("\n" + data.getString(1));
    }
    return listData.get(0);
}
```

> Method call, that doesn't show me the image

```
mImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(monitorData()));
```

Comment: `listData.get(0);` Well... what is in it? What is the value? Does it start with `content://....`.

Comment: `listData.get(0);` it is the first element from the database that contains content://media/external/images/media/47 string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you should remove `\n` symbol here:

```
listData.add(data.getString(1));
```